# database doesn't get information sent to it

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have been trying to find the problem for hours but I can't seem to find it.
My code is taking information from fields in registry form then sending it to Register.php using volley. the Register.php file should insert the data to the database but it's not happening for some reason

source codes:

**Register.php:**

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("http://shay.oversight-group.net/", "******", "*****", "shay_shay");


$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO user (name, age, username, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $age, $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;

echo json_encode $response; ?>
```

**android studio java codes:**

```
    public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        final EditText etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        final EditText etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

        bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String name = etName.getText().toString();
                final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                final int age = Integer.parseInt( etAge.getText().toString());

                final Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) { //When response is coming back from Register.php
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response); //New json object getting the response of register.php
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
                            if(success == true){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class); // moving to login activity if register was successful
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }else{
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this); //shows an error if register failed.
                                builder.setMessage("Register Failed").setNegativeButton("Retry", null).create().show(); //created the error alert
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };
                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(name, username, password, age, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}



public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://shay.oversight-group.net/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public RegisterRequest(String name, String username, String password, int age, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
        params.put("age", age+"");
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        System.out.println(params);
        return params;
    }
}
```

Comment: Password to a real database, yay!

Comment: change connection url with your `server ip address` or change to `localhost`

Comment: Check for errors using http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and on your query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php - If nothing comes of it, then it's an Android problem and I can't help you with that. @shaymishali

Comment: @Archish THANK YOU! solved my problem!! thank you!!